# Git revert followed by merge getting 'revert already in progress' error

Tags: git, merge, git-revert

Commits D & E were checked into branch XXX by mistake instead of YYY.  We are trying not to use `git reset` to solve this.

So we have:

- XXX: A -> B -> C -> D -> E
- YYY: A -> B -> C

We reverted to commit C on branch XXX

```
git checkout XXX
git revert --no-commit C..HEAD
git commit 
git push
```

This gets you

- XXX: A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F (F is the revert)
- YYY: A -> B -> C

Then we merged into branch YYY where we wanted to re-establish E as the head (without using reset).

```
git checkout YYY
git merge origin/XXX
```

So now we have:

- XXX: A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
- YYY: A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F

Then we tried to reset YYY to E

```
git revert --no-commit E..HEAD
```

BUT the revert commit gets you this error:

> error: a cherry-pick or revert is already in progress hint: try "git
>   cherry-pick (--continue | --quit | --abort)" fatal: revert failed

Tried using `--continue` but that didn't work.

How can we do this?

Comment: Why are you using `--no-commit` on the first `git revert` ?

Comment: Show us the full diagram of what `YYY` was at the start, and how you want it to look after merging `XXX` into it.

Comment: Re no-commit was following this advice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21718540/47281.  The --no-commit flag lets git revert all the commits at once- otherwise you'll be prompted for a message for each commit in the range, littering your history with unnecessary new commits.

Comment: Added the full diagram

Answer (score 0):

Passing `--no-commit` to `revert` and then trying to use `git checkout` to switch branches isn't going to work.

```
# First cleanup branch XXX
git checkout XXX
git revert C..HEAD
```

Here, there is no need to try to revert multiple times.  Just merge the original commits and then establish merge history for the revert

```
# now get the commits to YYY
git checkout YYY
git merge E 
git merge -s ours XXX
```

Comment: What is the issue with `--no-commit`?    I'm using `git commit` after this and pushing to the remote repo (updated question to be more clear).

Comment: @Marcus Leon - when you posted your question you were doing `git checkout` before you had committed.

Comment: Right, that was misleading.  Updated the question.